# How to reverse NAT by destination name

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, router, portforwarding, nat

I have one public IP Address and two web server inside my LAN. for example 10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.2 are the local IP address my Web servers. I have configured to NAT port 80 to 10.0.0.1 on my router. Just wondering if it's possible to reverse NAT in the router by name? If the request header is test1.com redirect to 10.0.0.1 and if it's test2.com redirect to 10.0.0.2. Or can I do that at IIS level?  I mean in the router redirect all 80 request to 10.0.0.1 and in the Webserver1 if the hostname is test2.com then redirect to 10.0.0.2.

Comment: Might I suggest you ask this question on http://serverfault.com/?  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Comment: Thank for your comment

Comment: Install ARR on 10.0.0.1 and forward all external traffic to it. Then set up ARR rules to distribute the traffic based on host name of incoming requests. That's rather typical scenarios and you can Google lots of posts.